# Color delimiters in listings differently from content

Tags: listings

I am trying to implement syntax highlighting in listings for XML. As a follow-up to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11134/1232), I have tried to grey-out the delimiters themselves, but have not had much luck despite a few attempts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colours
\colorlet{cdel}{blue}   % delimiters
\colorlet{ckey}{green}  % keywords
\colorlet{ccom}{gray}   % comments
\colorlet{cstr}{brown}  % strings
\colorlet{cide}{orange} % identifiers
\colorlet{ctxt}{black}  % text

% sets a function for moredelim to try to add
%   colored delimiters to the start and end
%      see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147848/1232
\def\beginlstdelim#1#2#3#4%
{%
    \def\endlstdelim{#2\egroup}%
    \color{#3}#1\bgroup\color{#4}\aftergroup\endlstdelim%
}

\lstdefinestyle{lst}{
    frame={single},
    basewidth=0.5em,    
    basicstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},   
    identifierstyle=\color{cide},
    keywordstyle=\color{ckey},
    stringstyle=\color{cstr},
    commentstyle=\color{ccom},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    columns=fixed,
    basewidth=0.5em
}

\lstdefinelanguage{xml}{ 
    keywords={xml},
    %literate={<}{{{\color{cdel}<}}}{1} {>}{{{\color{cdel}>}}}{1} {:}{{{\color{cdel}:}}}{1} {/}{{{\color{cdel}/}}}{1} {?}{{{\color{cdel}?}}}{1} {=}{{{\color{cdel}=}}}{1},  
       %^^ attempt 1: delimiters don't work
    %moredelim=**[is][\beginlstdelim{>}{<}{cdel}{ctxt}]{>}{<}, 
       %^^ attempt 2: messes with formatting    
    morestring=[s][\color{ctxt}]{>}{<},
    morestring=[b]",
    morecomment=[s]{!--}{--},
    morecomment=[s]{?}{?}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lst,language=xml]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mwe>
  <num>1</num>  <!-- the number is black -->
  <string xml:lang="en">Hello there</string>
  <comment>Why is this not black?</comment>
</mwe>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The code above gives:

[image]

(Don't worry; these are not the colours I will use in the end, but just used here to distinguish the different parts.)

What I would like is to grey out the delimiters (e.g, `<`, `>`, `/`, etc.). The code also includes a couple of (failed) attempts I made.

The first attempt was to use `literate` to append a color to the delimiters, but then other parts of the code cannot find those delimiters. The second attempt was to try to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147848/1232) using a custom function on `moredelim=**[is]` to append and prepend coloured delimiters, but this messes with the formatting a lot, plus it misses the opening `<` character. I know I can turn the delimiters grey by setting the `basicstyle`` grey, but then the text turns grey too.

---

Any ideas on how I can format the delimiters seperately from their content?

Answer (score 3):

If you want *every* `<` and `>` to have the same color, you can use low-level formating:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% colours
\colorlet{cdel}{blue}   % delimiters
\colorlet{ckey}{green}  % keywords
\colorlet{ccom}{gray}   % comments
\colorlet{cstr}{brown}  % strings
\colorlet{cide}{orange} % identifiers
\colorlet{ctxt}{black}  % text

% sets a function for moredelim to try to add
%   colored delimiters to the start and end
%      see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147848/1232
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"3C}{\lst@ttfamily{\textcolor{blue}{<}}{\textcolor{blue}{<}}}
     \lst@ProcessOther
     {"3E}{\lst@ttfamily{\textcolor{blue}{>}}{\textcolor{blue}{>}}}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{lst}{
    frame={single},
    basewidth=0.5em,
    basicstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},
    identifierstyle=\color{cide},
    keywordstyle=\color{ckey},
    stringstyle=\color{cstr},
    commentstyle=\color{ccom},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    columns=fixed,
    basewidth=0.5em
}

\lstdefinelanguage{xml}{
    keywords={xml},
    morestring=[s][\color{ctxt}]{>}{<},
    morestring=[b]",
    morecomment=[s]{!--}{--},
    morecomment=[s]{?}{?}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lst,language=xml]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mwe>
  <num>1</num>  <!-- the number is black -->
  <string xml:lang="en">Hello there</string>
  <comment>Why is this not black?</comment>
</mwe>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]