# Listing moredelim producing double delimiters

Tags: listings

I am trying to use the hack to highlight code between (but not including) two delimiters discussed in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270953/14751), but I am producing duplicate delimiters.

My goal is to highlight in orange everything between `by` (including the word "by") up until (but not including) a semicolon. So ideally `thus X by a,b,c;` would be highlighted as `thus X \textcolor{orange}{by a,b,c};`.

Here's a minimal working example with the bug:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=6.75in]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeOrange}{HTML}{fb7640}

\newcommand{\mizarByStyle}[1]{\ \textcolor{citeOrange}{by} \textcolor{citeOrange}{#1};}

\lstdefinelanguage{mizar}{
  morekeywords=[0]{->,(\#,\#),.=)},
  moredelim=[is][\mizarByStyle]{\ by}{;}
}

\lstnewenvironment{mizar}[1][]%
                  {\lstset{language=mizar,
                      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                      upquote=true}}%
                  {}

\begin{document}
\begin{mizar}
theorem Th3:
  for f being Element of Aut G
  holds f is Automorphism of G
proof
  let f be Element of Aut G;
  f is bijective Homomorphism of G,G by AUTGROUP:def 1;
  thus thesis;
end;
\end{mizar}
\end{document}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: Duplicate by keywords, this seems like a bug...]

**Addendum:** what I suspect is happening is that listings is treating `thus X by a:def 3;` as several "tokens" delimited between `by` and `;`, which then applies the `\mizarByStyle` to each "token". And if this *is* the case, is there any way to remedy the situation?

Almost certainly I will need to highlight situations like `thus X by a, b, c;` and the spaces between the `a`, `b`, and `c` would produce this "bug" all over again :(

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I am not the only one to experience this problem, and the solution can be found in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536920/14751). For my problem, the minimal working solution:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=6.75in]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeOrange}{HTML}{fb7640}

\def\beginlstdelim#1#2#3%
{%
    \def\endlstdelim{#2\egroup}%
    \textcolor{#3}{#1}\bgroup\color{#3}\aftergroup\endlstdelim%
}

\lstdefinelanguage{mizar}%
{
  keepspaces=true,
  alsoletter={\&,^,\\,\:,1234567890},
  morekeywords=[0]{->,(\#,\#),.=)},
  moredelim = **[is][{\beginlstdelim{\ by}{;}{citeOrange}}]{\ by}{;}
}

% everything else as before
```

This has some problems with whitespacing (as discussed in the other post) and is not as robust as I'd like (and I honestly don't understand why it needs to be `**[is]` but it must be, changing it to unstarred `[is]` doesn't work), but it's a "quick fix" to the problem at hand.